# Getting TRANSACTION_OVERSIZE error when submitting a transaction on the Hedera network

Tags: hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph

For Hedera File Service (HFS), I read that the file size limit is 1MB but each transaction is only limited to 6Kb.

The documentation says that we can use FileAppend to add the additional contents so - Does this mean that if I do want to upload a 1MB file, I’d have to do it in increments of 6Kb size transactions?

Right now I'm getting a TRANSACTION_OVERSIZE error

Answer (score 3):

The limit per message is 1kb, and the total size for a given transaction is limited to 6kb (including signatures, transaction Id, etc.) by the network. If you exceed this, you may receive a TRANSACTION_OVERSIZE error.

A common alternative is to use IPFS and link metadata. HFS is only recommended for specific use cases.

Comment: So what's the 1 MB limit refers to in the documentation?